# Responsive Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, responsive-design

How to make a responsive google map from the code

```
<div class="map">
    <iframe>...</iframe>
</div>
```

I use in css for full map

```
.map{max-width:100%;}
```

and small device

```
.map{max-width:40%;}
```

but it didn't work.

Anyone have idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 66):

Add this to your initialize function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  // Resize stuff...
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(center); 
  });

}

</script>
```

Comment: i dont know the performance on this though, but you got my good calification anyway.

Comment: If you're going with this option, you should wrap it in a `setTimemout`, so it does not run continuously. e.g. `var resizeTimeout; google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() { if (resizeTimeout) { clearTimeout(resizeTimeout); } resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() { /* do resizing */ }, 250); });`

Comment: Because of some reason, when resize stuff is wrapped in setTimeout function, it stops working.

Comment: This may seem stupid but how do I add this to my "Initialize Function"? I tried adding it to my header where all my other scripts are and I keep getting syntax errors. Where exactly am I supposed to put this code?

Comment: Remember you can always remove the event listener after you're done with the resize. 

i.e. 

    `function remove(){  
        EventTarget.removeEventListener(window, 'resize', ()=>{
                //handle setting of finished dimensions here. 
        })
    }`

Comment: Works perfectly! Love this answer!

Answer (score 64):

Adding a **100%** to the **width** and **height** attributes of its iframe has always worked for me. For example

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=+&amp;q=surat&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Surat,+Gujarat&amp;ll=21.195,72.819444&amp;spn=0.36299,0.676346&amp;t=m&amp;z=11&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br />
```

Comment: Apparently this was allowed in older versions of HTML, but in HTML5 width must be expressed in pixels. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_width.asp

Comment: Simple, beautiful solution. KISS

Comment: This better for all iframes, like YouTube embedding, etc. Thank you @Nimsrules

Answer (score 29):

A solution without javascript:

HTML:

```
<div class="google-maps">
<iframe>........//Google Maps Code//..........</iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.google-maps {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75%; // This is the aspect ratio
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.google-maps iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you have a custom map size, remove the "height: 100% !important"

Comment: Thats a good solution. Do iframe with 2600px; .google-maps { overflow-hiddem; width:100%; } .google-maps iframe { left:50%; margin-left: -1300px } THank you for idea

Answer (score 9):

It's better to use Google Map API.
I've created an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/eugenebolotin/8m1s69e5/1/

Key features are using of functions:

```
//Full example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/eugenebolotin/8m1s69e5/1/

map.setCenter(map_center);
// Scale map to fit specified points
map.fitBounds(path_bounds);
```

It handles resize event and automaticaly adjusts size.

Comment: Your example is a good one. It would have been best one if you could resize without having to store `path_bounds` because in my case it is very tough to manage `path_bounds`

Answer (score 6):

in the iframe tag, you can easily add width='100%' instead of the preset value giving to you by the map

like this:

```
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?anyLocation" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this for a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/5AEEV/

I can't take the credit for the code though, it comes from [quick and easy way to make google maps iframe embed responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370115/quick-and-easy-way-to-make-google-maps-iframe-embed-responsive).

Good luck!

**CSS**

```
#map_canvas{
width:50%;
height:300px !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <style>
      html, body, #map_canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've been looking for some time to get this solution, it appears googlemaps does not enjoy if both width and height are percentages. But your solution does indeed work, somehow! cheers

Answer (score 2):

Here a standard CSS solution + JS for the map's height resizing

CSS

```
#map_canvas {
   width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
// On Resize
$(window).resize(function(){ 
    $('#map_canvas').height($( window ).height());
```

JsFiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/3VKQ8/33/

Answer (score 1):

i think the simplest way will be to add this css and it will work perfectly.

```
embed, object, iframe{max-width: 100%;}
```

Comment: I believe it doesn't. The height doesn't change proportionally.

Comment: you always have to give height. or add media queries to create different height on different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

## My Responsive [Solution] Google Map in Foundation 4 Modal

---

**JS**

Create an external JavaScript file (i.e. mymap.js) with the following code

```js
google.maps.visualRefresh = true; //Optional

var respMap;

function mymapini() {
    var mapPos = new google.maps.LatLng(-0.172175,1.5); //Set the coordinates
    var mapOpts = {
    zoom: 10, //You can change this according your needs
    disableDefaultUI: true, //Disabling UI Controls (Optional)
    center: mapPos, //Center the map according coordinates
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    respMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mymap'),
      mapOpts);

    var mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: mapPos,
          map: respMap,
          title: 'You can put any title'
      });

    //This centers automatically to the marker even if you resize your window
    google.maps.event.addListener(respMap, 'idle', function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      respMap.panTo(mapPos.getPosition());
    }, 250);    
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', mymapini);

$("#modalOpen").click(function(){ //Use it like <a href="#" id="modalOpen"...
    $("#myModal").show(); //ID from the Modal <div id="myModal">...
    google.maps.event.trigger(respMap, 'resize');
});
```

**HTML**

Add the following code before the  tag:

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="js/mymap.js"></script>
```

Add this to the modal code:

```html
<div id="mymap"></div>
```

**CSS**

Add this to your stylesheet:

```css
#mymap { margin: 0; padding: 0; width:100%; height: 400px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Responsive with CSS**
You can make the Iframe responsive with the following CSS codes.

```
.map {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 26.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.map iframe,
.map object,
.map embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Responsive with JavaScript**

This possible through `window.resize` event and you can apply this on google map like `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', initialize);`

Consider the following example:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
           zoom: 9,
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.9285745, 77.09149350000007),  
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           map: map,
           draggable: false,
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(28.9285745, 77.09149350000007)
     });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', initialize);
```

Take a look for more details - https://webomnizz.com/how-to-make-responsive-google-map-with-google-map-api/

Comment: it's going to introduce memory leak because there is no way for disposing map and marker elements. You really should use google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

Answer (score 0):

Tried it with CSS, but its never 100% responsive, so I built a pure javascript solution. This one uses jQuery,

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {

  var center = map.getCenter();

  resizeMap();

  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  map.setCenter(center);

});



function resizeMap(){

  var h = window.innerHeight;
  var w = window.innerWidth;

  $("#map_canvas").width(w/2);
  $("#map_canvas").height(h-50);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution based on eugenemail response:

**1. HTML** - Google Maps API

[Get API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

**2. HTML** - Canvas

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

**3. CSS** - Map canvas

```
#map_canvas {
    height: 400px;
}
```

**4. JavaScript**

```
function initialize() {
    var lat = 40.759300;
    var lng = -73.985712;
    var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: map_center,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        map.setCenter(map_center);
    });
}
initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am an amateur but I found this worked:

```
.maps iframe {
    position: absolute;
}

body {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 820px;
    height: available;
}
```

There may be a bit of whitespace at the bottom but I am satified