# Google maps set different zoom based on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Following to my previous question [Google maps responsive resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444161/google-maps-responsive-resize) I would like to implement a different zoom level based on windows resize, **while resizing**, so if browser windows is "less than" apply x number of zooming and if "major than" apply another zooming level automatically and on the fly.

The following code works perfectly in regards of recentering the map on windows resize, I need to apply the new zoom levels to it:

```
var map; 
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.5472,12.282715),
  zoom: 6,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
      mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
  var center = map.getCenter();
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  map.setCenter(center); 
  map.setZoom(zoom level needs to be automatically set according to window size);
});
```

Comment: probably simplest to determine the bounds that you want visible and use map.fitBounds rather than map.setCenter.

Comment: Does the map need to contain a specific set of points? Are there any other details you can provide?

Comment: the map needs to contain a specific area with specific LatLng, the values are provided in the code above, the markers will be contained within this area

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Construct the area you want to always be in view by creating a [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) and call [map.fitBounds()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) as suggested by geocodezip.

Comment: If I wanted the full map to be always be displayed, what would my LatLangBounds be?

Comment: I've selected my south east and north west corners but at times when I'm resizing my browser the zoom level exposes what I have set beyond my coordinates.

Comment: I use `fitBounds`, but I am not satisfied with the zoom level in some cases. Let's say I want a smaller zoom for "ROOFTOP". I'm trying to use `setZoom` method, but it is ignored...