# How can I center and zoom Google Maps after resizing the map container?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with many markers.

[image]

After resizing the map, it looks like this:

[image]

and I want this:

[image]

How can I zoom in and center the map on the markers after resizing?

I have the following code;

```
var map;

var GoogleMaps = {
  setMarkers: function(stores){
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'));

    $.each(stores, function (key, store) {
      /* (..) */
      bounds.extend(latLng);
    });

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    // This part is never triggered
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
      var center = map.getCenter();
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
      map.setCenter(center);    
    });
  }
}
```

HTML
When I click the resize icon, I add a css class to `map-canvas`

```
<div class="map-container alt-row row-spacer clearfix">
  <section class="column12">
    <div id="map-canvas" class=""></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I've looked at similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517053/centering-google-maps-on-responsive-resize-with-marker) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444161/google-maps-responsive-resize)), but they do not solve my problem.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? You can [look at my JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/d7fykbzm/6/).

Comment: If you downvote, at least comment why.

Answer (score 0):

*Re-setting* the map to fit the bounds should work when the `map` div is resized:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 'resize', function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the DOM listener is never triggered. I tried and added `console.log('test')` - but no output.

Comment: I added the HTML code for the map. I think the listener is on the wrong DOM element. I tried `google.maps.event.addDomListener($('.map-container'), 'resize', ` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Is $('.map-container') a DOM element or an array of DOM elements?

Comment: It's the DIV that gets resized - as you can see above.

Comment: Looking closer at my code, I See that I'm adding a class to the `map-canvas` element. So it's not the container that gets resized, but the map canvas. That means using `document.getElementById('map-canvas')` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `idle` instead of `resize` event for that purpose.

**Example**

```js
var map;

var GoogleMaps = {
    setMarkers: function (stores) {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'));

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        $.each(stores, function (key, store) {

            var storePos = new google.maps.LatLng(store[1], store[2]);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: storePos,
                title: store[0],
                map: map
            });


            bounds.extend(storePos);
        });

        map.fitBounds(bounds);


        /*google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'resize', function () {
            var center = map.getCenter();
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            map.setCenter(center);
        });*/

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function (event) {
            var center = map.getCenter();
            map.setCenter(center);
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += 'Adjusted..';
        });
    }
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
    var stores = [
        ['0183 Oslo, Norja', 59.918816, 10.751814],
        ['1154 Oslo, Norja', 59.873011, 10.814299],
        ['0264 Oslo, Norja', 59.916751, 10.705809]
    ];
    GoogleMaps.setMarkers(stores);
});
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id='result'/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't get it working though. Tried with both `resize` and `idle`. Can you take a look at my Fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/d7fykbzm/6/