# Gmap3 replace adress by gps coordinates and responsive mode

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, responsive, jquery-gmap3

I have this code for my gmap3 and I would like to:

1. Replace my address with GPS coordinates
2. Put my marker at the center when I resize my page.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#adresse').gmap3({
        marker: {
            address: " Apple CAP 3000 Avenue Eugène Donadeï, 06700 Saint-Laurent Du Var, France"
        },
        map: {
            options: {
                zoom: 17
            }
       }
    });
});
```

UPDATES

at this time I work on your first point, I replaced the marker line to have lat & long instead of adress but it doesn't work. I did something wrong ?

```
{marker: { address: " Apple CAP 3000 Avenue Eugène Donadeï, 06700 Saint-Laurent Du Var, France" },
```

by

```
{marker: { geometry: "lat: 37.4220323, lng: -122.0845109"},
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Replace my address with GPS coordinates**

You can use [Geocoding process](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Geocoding) to convert addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use to place markers on a map, or position the map. The **Google Maps Geocoding API** provides a direct way to access these services via an HTTP request. You can check [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Geocoding) the example which uses the Geocoding service through the Google Maps JavaScript API to demonstrate the basic functionality.

> A Google Maps Geocoding API request takes the following form:
>
> `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/outputFormat?parameters`
>
> where `outputFormat` may be either of the following values:
>
> - `json` (recommended) indicates output in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON); or
> - `xml` indicates output in XML
>
> To access the Google Maps Geocoding API over HTTP, use:
>
> `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/outputFormat?parameters`

**2. Put my marker at the center when I resize my page.**

You can check on these related SO posts:

- [Google maps responsive resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444161/google-maps-responsive-resize)

> Move your map variable into a scope where the event listener can use
>   it.  You are creating the map inside your initialize() function and
>   nothing else can use it when created that way.
>
> ```
> var map; //<-- This is now available to both event listeners and the initialize() function
> function initialize() {
>   var mapOptions = {
>    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.5472,12.282715),
>    zoom: 6,
>    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
>   };
>   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
>             mapOptions);
> }
> google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
> google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
>  var center = map.getCenter();
>  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
>  map.setCenter(center); 
> });
> ```

- [Centering Google Maps on responsive resize with marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517053/centering-google-maps-on-responsive-resize-with-marker)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks for your answer it's clear ;D I updated my question to give you more details because I tried to change the address marker my geometry marker but it doesn't work ?