# How do I get DIV to ignore browser changes

Tags: html, css

Whenever I load my page in full screen (F11 mode) my `<div>` takes up the full screen as expected.

However when it's not in full screen the `<div>` only takes up the full screen of the current browser. When I hit F11 and go back into full screen it leaves a large white border at the bottom of the page.

The same goes for when I load the page up with any dev tools open after I close the dev tools the page leaves a white blank space in the place of where the dev tools were open.

How can I ignore the browser toolbars and whatnot.

Thats the `<div>` I'm trying to keep the full size of the page.

```
#mapCanvas{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: I suspect you would need to use JavaScript for this, as I don't think CSS knows when changes have been made to the window.

Comment: That's because the CSS isn't dynamic. It loads 100% of whatever screen you load it in.

Comment: because you do `position: absolute`, then the calculated height & width is taken from that moment the page loaded, if you change browser size, its not re-calculeted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some javascript

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("mapCanvas").style.height = "100%";
    document.getElementById("mapCanvas").style.width = "100%";
};
```

Comment: I was going to submit it in jQuery but I didn't know if you were using it or if you were going to have to add new libraries. Glad to help.

Comment: @Farris Ismati Why would he use jquery instead ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're including something like google maps. This actually embeds an `iframe` into the document with set width and height attributes which will not size automatically once loaded.

What you'll need to do is add a resize event handler in JavaScript and reload the canvas on a window resize.

An example for doing this with google maps can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444161/google-maps-responsive-resize).

Answer (score 0):

See the demo http://jsfiddle.net/a7nzy6w6/1/

CSS

```
#myDiv.fullscreen{
z-index: 9999; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
position: fixed; 
top: 0; 
left: 0;
```

}

```
#myDiv{background:#cc0000; width:500px; height:400px;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <div id="myDiv">
       my div
      <button>Full Screen</button>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
$('button').click(function(e){
$('#myDiv').toggleClass('fullscreen'); 
});
```

The trick is in setting position:fixed, by toggling the .fullscreen class. This takes it outside of the normal dom tree, so to speak, and sizes/positions it relative to the window.