# Responsive offset (panBy) while resize. Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I had a similar question before but since id lead to a dead end and I have developed a new understanding I am on a different point of view right now. My question now would be how to handle this instead with media queries and panBy with an offset which is newly calculated with every resize

I use this code (Updated):

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    var Name = {lat: XX, lng: XX};

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: Name,
        map: map,
        title: 'Name!'
    });

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(XX, XX),
        zoom: 13,
        zoomControl: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        draggable: false,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        overviewMapControlOptions: {
            opened: false,
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: styleArray
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);


        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: markericon,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][5], locations[i][6]),
            map: map,
            title: locations[i][0],
            desc: description,
            tel: telephone,
            email: email,
            web: web
        });

    }
    var mql = window.matchMedia(("(max-height: 750px)"));
    mql.addListener(new function(){
    if(window.matchMedia("(max-height: 750px)").matches){
    map.panBy(0, 150);
  }else {
    map.panBy(0, 250);
  }});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(center);

});
```

Thanks for reading!
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using the [panBy](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) method. Instead, use your map object variable inside an event listener which you can manipulate as instructed in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444161/google-maps-responsive-resize).

Comment: well my script in full looks exactly like that i got it from this page but i still cant figure out how to apply the offset newly calculated on every resize.