# Google Maps iframe responsive issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, iframe

I've tried to make the google iframe map responsive, but when viewed on mobile, the map remains the same size instead of resizing. I've tried replacing the code multiple times (based on answers found here), but have not found the solution to my problem. Would appreciate if someone could point out my mistake.

```
/* Google Map */
.google-maps {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 75%; // This is the aspect ratio
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .google-maps iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12" class="google-maps">
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1vQ8RDv0RplunNZfvdhgPTtCSjGA" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set some rules for the [iframe](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide). By setting an absolute position we are telling the  that it can take up the space of its parents padding and height. To position the iframe within the parent element (cc-map-wrapper), we use top and left properties. Lastly, by adding width and height we obtain the responsive look we are after.

```
.cc-map-wrapper {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
padding-top: 25px;
height: 0;
}
.cc-map-wrapper iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Here's a related SO ticket which discuss how to make a responsive Google maps: [Responsive Google Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421369/responsive-google-map)

Answer (score 0):

Is using Javascript an option? 
I would just go for making the iframe `width:100%` and using JS to set the height according to your chosen aspect ratio.

For example you can use jQuery :

```
$('.google-maps>iframe').height(
    $('.google-maps>iframe').outerWidth()*3/4
); //for a 4:3 aspect ratio
```

Comment: That now fits mobile but no longer for desktop (same size for mobile and desktop).

Comment: That's when bootstrap comes in to do the job. Do you know how to use bootstrap's grid? `class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12"` should make the div full-width on small devices and half-width of the containing `.row` on bigger screens.

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted, but it really was a smooth solution. even mentioning of the width to be assigned as 100% was spot on