# Embedding Google Maps - "View on Google Maps" Link Broken on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, mobile, embed

I've used the "Share and Embed" map option to put a map on a site I'm developing (from the cog at the bottom of the "new" Google Maps:

[image: MapsShareAndEmbed]

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2426.5340551802665!2d-1.3732330000000013!3d52.541864000000004!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x48775aa3a9b0d003%3A0x733a43420fa646be!2sAT+Home+Furniture!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1392282549357" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

On desktop, it works fine, you can click on "View on Google Maps" and it works as you'd expect and shows the shop location on Google Maps. However, when you click this link on a mobile device (Nexus 5, iPad 3, Nexus 7), it just opens the Google Maps app to the general area, and people have to then type a search in manually to find the shop (screenshot of what appears is below).

Surely this isn't a bug with Google Maps? What have I done wrong? Do other people experience this in the same way?

The link to the site currently is: [AT Home Furniture](http://www.athomefurniturehinckley.com/dev/findus)

**2014-02-25 EDIT -** If there's no way to fix this (Google have surely overlooked something here?!), then is it possible to replicate this (a map customised to the user if they're logged in) with the API? If you view the site you should see this in action, but it's the standard functionality of Google Maps when embedded in an iFrame.

**2014-02-26 EDIT -** If I use the Google Maps API, how would I go about putting a link to the "full map" (open it in Google Maps) which worked on desktop AND mobile?

[image: Google Maps Embed Broken On Mobile Devices]

Comment: w3c validator reports some errors for your page content. Check it, maybe there is something which could be improved.

Comment: Everything now validates fully :) problem still happens (obviously).

Comment: The solution to your problem is explained here very well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370115/quick-and-easy-way-to-make-google-maps-iframe-embed-responsive

Comment: You're saying I should be using the Google Maps API instead of embedding it with their provided iFrame code? What's the reason for the iFrame one simply not working on mobile? Seems a bit bizarre!

Comment: The embed code was not designed well for mobile, which is why they developed the Google Maps v3 API.  The API is designed to be used seamlessly across platforms.

Comment: Here is a good summary and useful info:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370115/quick-and-easy-way-to-make-google-maps-iframe-embed-responsive

Comment: @JacquesGoulet That example has no marker on the map.. so if I used the API, how would I make a link which someone on a mobile would click to open the location on Google Maps properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom map API info window to display the share map link etc.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/PEHba/7/

You can add as many markers you want. Just put lines 8-13 in a loop. All the information to be displayed when clicked on the marker has to be contained inside the marker. When clicked, we use this.xyz to access them.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load',       function() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.54215, -1.37335),
        zoom: 14
    });
    //add a marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.542151, -1.373351),
        map: map,
        title:"Hello World!",
        View_on_Google_Maps_link: 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/AT+Home+Furniture/@52.541864,-1.373233,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x733a43420fa646be?hl=en-GB'
    });

    //attach a click event to the marker to display the info window.
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        //create a info window to show when a maker is clicked
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<div>Share link: '+ this.View_on_Google_Maps_link +'.</div>'
        }); 
        infowindow.open(map,this);
    });



});
```

Comment: Great answer, but don't suppose you know of a URL I can put **in** the InfoWindow which will open the "place" on Google Maps desktop and mobile? On a browser on my Desktop, the link you used opens fine and shows all the business info, but on mobile, it doesn't appear. You *can* get a similar screen on mobile, because when you search for the business name on the Google Maps mobile app, you get an info screen.

Comment: @BT643 I'm not sure if you can add direct link to the place on mobile, but you can add a get directions link like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PEHba/15/

Also worth checking the Google places settings for the store, does the same happen if you try to link to more popular place like the Hinkley Museum?

Comment: Haven't actually tried linking to a more popular place, but thanks for your answer(s)! This should get me what I want I think :) Thanks again!